# When refreshing a pivot table, can you force a field to display certain values?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

Say I have a pivot table with the field "favourite colours" in the Columns with a Count of the Values.

The options for that field are "red", "blue", "green" or "yellow" and when I create the pivot table, there are rows in the data source that include instances of each of these colours so all four columns appear on the table.

[image: Initial pivot table result]

If the data source is updated and now there are no people who selected, say, "blue" as a colour, when I refresh the pivot table it will remove that "blue column" as there is no data to report.

[image: Blue disappears from columns]

Can I force the pivot somehow to still show that "blue" option for the "favourite colours" field, even though there are no instances of that colour in the data source?

I suppose I'm asking if you can show a field value in a column that has a grand total of zero? Maybe using VBA?

[image: What I'd like it to show]

Comment: I can fudge it by adding each of the colour options to the data source in some hidden rows and then ensuring that I minus 1 from the totals, but that's not very pleasant...

Comment: That "blue" has to come from *somewhere*. The pivot table can't base its contents on how it looked "previously", such a thing would be fraught with peril. If the full set of colors is known (or can be retrieved), you can simply make a new table that aggregates the first table (so not a pivot) with `COUNTIF` . If that's "too much work" or you do need some flexibility from the pivot, use that table as a base to lookup aggregated values in the pivot table (`MATCH`/`OFFSET`, `VLOOKUP`, `HLOOKUP` or `GETPIVOTDATA`/`IFERROR`). Fudging the source would indeed be quite ugly, I wouldn't go that route.